# Is 菜心 used in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese, proper-nouns, food

Is the vegetable 菜心 (Choy Sum - English rendering of Cantonese) called 菜心 in Mandarin? Is it pronounced "cài xīn" or is it pronounced as it would be in Cantonese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I spoke Mandarin in Guangzhou, I -- and the people I was talking to -- called it 菜心, càixīn. Outside of Guangzhou, I heard it called 广东菜心, Guàngdōng càixīn.

Answer (score 2):

菜心 is Mandarin. 通指青菜的心。在很多菜名中有用到，比如果香菇菜心。

Answer (score 2):

In Taiwan at least definitely called 菜心 and pronounced "cài xīn".